# Converting epoch number to human readable date in mysql

Tags: mysql, epoch

I have a epoch number say 1389422614485.
The datatype for the value storing this value is varchar.
I want to convert its value to human readable time.
How can we do it?
Any example for this conversion?

Comment: It should be noted, unix epoch time is a 32-bit integer as of now and can't be greater than 2147483647.  It also makes more sense to store it as an INT.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Your epoch value `1389422614485` seems like having the millisecond precision. So you need to use some mysql mathematical functions along with `from_unixtime()` for generating human readable format.

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(floor(1389422614485/1000));
+------------------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(floor(1389422614485/1000)) |
+------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-11 12:13:34                      |
+------------------------------------------+
```

**Update July 2020:** As of MySQL 8.0, the `floor` function is no longer necessary when working with milliseconds:

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1594838230234/1000);
+------------------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1594838230234/1000)        |
+------------------------------------------+
| 2020-07-15 18:37:10.2340                 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks buddy,  worked for me. Has been stuck with this one

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at [from-unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
       -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use from_unixtime() as follows:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(1388618430);
```

which returns 2014-01-02 00:20:30

Comment: @user3675548: what mysql version are you using? and what value?

Comment: If you're using a unix epoch specified in milliseconds (instead of seconds) FROM_UNIXTIME() of this value will return NULL. If this is the case, use FLOOR() of your value divided by 1000, as shown in the other answers

Comment: I got `2014-01-01 23:20:30`

Comment: @sttaq the reason for this might be that you have another timezone configured. unfortunately this function returns values depending on that.

Comment: Thanks, yup I realized that later that mysql converts the epoch time to local time zone.

Answer (score 3):

This wil work for both `+positive` and `-negative` epoch, in-case for old birth dates, and also if you want to specify date format

```
select
date_format(DATE_ADD(from_unixtime(0), interval '1389422614485'/1000 second), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as my_new_date;
```